# Is there a way to add a column to a table in PowerPoint slide through Python?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have a powerpoint template which I want to use to create a monthly report. The number of columns in one of the table on the slide can change based on some logic and I would like to add new column during runtime.

I was looking for a method to add a column but couldn't find one. The python-pptx documentation lists an **add(before)** method under **_ColumnCollection** class but I think it is not yet available.

Does anyone know of any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new table of the desired shape.

```
>>> shape = table_placeholder.insert_table(rows=..., cols=...)
>>> table = shape.table
```

Copy the contents from your last table to the new table. **Also, add new values here.** Example code:

```
>>> cell_old = table_old.cell(0, 0)
>>> cell_new = table_new.cell(0, 0)
>>> cell_new.text = cell_old.text
```

Delete your old table.

Comment: I had this idea but I do not want to delete the table as it is part of a template which is managed by the users. This way I do not have to worry about theme, formatting etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that changes the old table to a new table

with this function, you can extend the new table and fill same values from the old table

Imagine we have a table that has 2 rows and 4 columns

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

and you want to extend it 4 rows and 6 columns and fill the same values from the old table

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**My Code**

```
def changeTable(new_table,old_table):
        rowIndex = 0
        cellIndex = 0
        for row in old_table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                new_table.cell(rowIndex,cellIndex).text = cell.text
                cellIndex = cellIndex + 1
            cellIndex = 0    
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1

old_table = shp.table
new_table = slide.shapes.add_table(4,6,shp.left,shp.top,shp.width,shp.height).table
changedTable = changeTable(new_table,old_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use other approach:

```
    from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement
    
    def _sub_element(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
        element = OxmlElement(tagname)
        element.attrib.update(kwargs)
        parent.append(element)
        return element
    
    def _sub_element_insert(parent, index, tagname, **kwargs):
        element = OxmlElement(tagname)
        element.attrib.update(kwargs)
        parent.insert(index, element)
        return element
    
    def insert_column(shape, at_position, width):
        table = shape.table
        tbl = table._tbl

        trs = tbl.xpath(r"a:tr")
    
        for tr in trs:
            tc = _sub_element_insert(tr, at_position, "a:tc")
            txBody = _sub_element(tc, "a:txBody")
            bodyPr = _sub_element(txBody, "a:bodyPr")
            lstStyle = _sub_element(txBody, "a:lstStyle")
            p = _sub_element(txBody, "a:p")
            tcPr = _sub_element(tc, "a:tcPr", marL="0", marR="0", marT="0", marB="0", anchor="ctr")
    
        tblGrid = tbl.tblGrid
        gridCol = _sub_element_insert(tblGrid, at_position, "a:gridCol", w=str(width*12700))
```

The *width* is in **pt**s.

This, in addition to inserting a column, can also add one - just set the position one greater than the existing column's count.